# Elasticsearch copy only index mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch 6-nodes cluster version 6.8.1
How to copy only mappings from existing index to new index without data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[elasticdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump) can do that easily with the following command:

```
elasticdump \
  --input=http://source_host:9200/source_index \
  --output=http://target_host:9200/target_index \
  --type=mapping
```

Comment: With great pleasure :-)